# Pinterest redirect_uri query parameter

Tags: api, redirect, uri, pinterest

In my Pinterest app I have set the Redirect URI to `https://my.site.com/pinterest/callback`. When doing the redirection after authentication back to my site I append a sessionid so the query becomes `https://my.site.com/pinterest/callback?sessionid=<string>`. This doesn't seem to work as I get

> The provided redirect_uri https://my.site.com/pinterest/callback?sessionId=YA6udv2FrdjjV8juij3U5oIBBP6RoEQWWUFNzSHKaHGGf3jRq10uJ2A0-R-eYB8LLwiBTbESEdGzMY0fhYI8d7gOe3kOoPuPS6c-mowaaJBDv0J8D2I does not match any of the registered redirect URIs."

In other apis like the Instagram one this is possible. Can anyone help with this? Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Try adding an ending `/` to the redirect URI. Sometimes it is very picky.

Comment: Sorry that didn't help.

Comment: @zaxme Did you find any solution to this?

Comment: I don't have access to the project anymore and cannot recall. I suggest checking out if Pinterest has approved your app. I remember that that was an issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been stucking with this for two days. Basically, Pinterest doesn't support custom parameters like other websites do, for Pinterest you need to provide the **EXACT** callback url and it has to use *https* not *http*, and if you need to pass custom parameters they should be in state parameter.

From Pinterest docs

> state: A value you define. This can be used to make sure that the redirect back to your site or app wasn’t spoofed.

See *Authentication* section at https://developers.pinterest.com/docs/api/overview/